# C# String.PadRight performance vs. concatenating string + substring of pad characters

Tags: c#, string, performance, padding

Not really a question, but I didn't find any answer, so I ran some tests myself, and thought others might benefit.

First the question:

When padding a (lot of) strings to a predefined length with a predefined character, is it faster to use `String.PadRight()` or to concatenate the string with the substring of a pre-set string of padding chars?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to pad or concatenate. So this question can only be answered by yourself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you greatly underesimate the difficulty of correct and meaningful benchmarking. - You also might want to hve a look at the c# sources!

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well, I originally had both question and the answer below in one post, until I saw I could split them up directly. But since I posted my answer at the same time as the question, I assumed whoever didn't find the question alone sufficient could get more info about what exactly my goal is from the answer as well ;)

Comment: @TaW Oh, no question that I still have lots to learn. This was just exactly how much time I was able to invest into this—I was mainly trying to check if using one or the other way in a similar fashion as I need to in my application would result in a big performance penalty (or advantage), so that I could avoid problems in that area in the first place.

Comment: You may (or may not) enjoy reading a few of [these links](https://www.google.com/search?q=premature+optimization&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b)

Answer (score 2):

I ran the test myself after I couldn't find an answer (that's the reason for the post in the first place).

My results were as follows (similar over multiple runs)

```
direct String.PadRight average: 29,291921 ms.
String.PadRight average:        32,328434 ms.
Custom PadRight average:        27,066596 ms.
```

with

```
private const int Iterations = 500;
private const int NumStrings = 250000;
private const int TestStringLength = 50;
```

for a test in which I generated `NumStrings` random strings of less than `TestStringLength` characters and then padded all of them to `TestStringLength` with blanks.

So the substring-based padding seems to have been faster (but of course less versatile). Interestingly, this trend is reversed the fewer strings are padded and the fewer iterations are run. Then, `String.PadRight` gets faster quickly.

The testing code ([here a dotnetfiddle version](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Kd9fA0) [reduced counts to make it work there, and you can't trust the results you get there, they vary a LOT from run to run]):

```
#region Performance Test
private const int Iterations = 500;
private const int NumStrings = 250000;
private const int TestStringLength = 50;

private static string EmptyLine;

public static string PadRight(string input)
{
    return input.PadRight(TestStringLength, ' ');
}
public static string PadRight2(string input)
{
    return input + EmptyLine.Substring(0, TestStringLength - input.Length);
}
#endregion // Performance Test
```

with the loop being

```
#region Performance Test

EmptyLine = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(" ", TestStringLength));

var random = new System.Random();
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
string[] randomStrings = new string[NumStrings];
double[] averageDirect = new double[Iterations];
double[] averageStandard = new double[Iterations];
double[] averageCustom = new double[Iterations];

// init random strings
for (int i = 0; i < NumStrings; ++i)
{
    temp.Clear();
    for (int k = 0; k < random.Next(0, TestStringLength); ++k)
    {
        temp.Append((char)('!' + random.Next(0, 93)));
    }
    randomStrings[i] = temp.ToString();
}

var timer = new Stopwatch();
string padded;

for (int counter = 0; counter < Iterations; ++counter)
{
    timer.Reset();

    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumStrings; ++i)
    {
        padded = PadRight2(randomStrings[i]);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    averageCustom[counter] = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    timer.Reset();

    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumStrings; ++i)
    {
        padded = PadRight(randomStrings[i]);
    }
    timer.Stop();
    averageStandard[counter] = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    timer.Reset();

    timer.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumStrings; ++i)
    {
        padded = randomStrings[i].PadRight(TestStringLength, ' ');
    }
    timer.Stop();
    averageDirect[counter] = timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
}

Console.WriteLine($"direct String.PadRight average: {averageDirect.Average()} ms.");
Console.WriteLine($"String.PadRight average: {averageStandard.Average()} ms.");
Console.WriteLine($"Custom PadRight average: {averageCustom.Average()} ms.");

#endregion // Performance Test
```

Comment: Side-note: i can recommend to use [BenchmarkDotNet](http://benchmarkdotnet.org/) for such tests. Easy to use with much more accurate results. Remember to run tests compiled as release and without attached debugger(so for example as a console application that isn't stared in visual studio). Of course the tests itself should only test what they should and not unrelated code(f.e. what is equal for both approaches).